# Javascript: Update img src by id, depending on the day

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write a function that changes the picture on the website according to the day. When I do this the picture shows up as broken. Can anyone tell me why? Is it because I have a bunch of styles applied to the picture in CSS?

```
var now = new Date ();
var day = now.getDay();

if(day == 0)
document.getElementById("food").src = "images/salad.jpg";
```

There is my javascript, and here is the corresponding html:

```
<section >
  <img  id='food' src='#' ></img>
</section>
```

Comment: It's because your path to the image is incorrect

Comment: I'm pretty sure the path is correct. it's in the images folder titled as salad.jpg. the images folder is in the same place as both my html file and my js file

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: yeah, i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null"

Comment: Are you executing your JavaScript code before the element exists on the page?

Comment: Oh man, that was totally the issue. I linked to the script too early in my html doc. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing it on DOM ready

```
window.onload = (function(){
var now = new Date ();
var day = now.getDay();

if(day == 0)
document.getElementById("food").src = "images/salad.jpg";
})();
```

And please make sure that if `day is not equal to 0` no image will load and thus you will see an image error icon.

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLg8uw13/)**

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you place your javascript code AFTER the HTML so the JS has something to execute on.
2. When I alert the var `day` I get 1, not 0. Not sure if this matters.
3. There is no closing `</img>` tag, and you also don't need to have `src='#'`, just leave `src` out.